# ionic geolocation: make watchposition check every 1 minute

Tags: android, cordova, parse-platform, geolocation, ionic-framework

In my ionic app i need to record the gps cordinates to parse core backend.

```
  var opts={
        enableHighAccuracy:true,
        timeout: 8000,
        maximumAge: 5000
    };
    var watch = $cordovaGeolocation.watchPosition(opts).then(function () { /* Not  used */
           },
           function (err) {

           }, function (position) {
             var lat  = position.coords.latitude;
             var long = position.coords.longitude;
             $scope.slat=lat;
             $scope.slong=long;
             var uob=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('meemp'));
             console.log(uob);
             var point = new Parse.GeoPoint({latitude: lat, longitude: long});
             console.log(point);
             console.log(uob["objectId"]);
             $timeout(function() {
               var PeopleObject = Parse.Object.extend("PeopleObject");
               var person = new PeopleObject();
               person.set("lat", point);
               person.set("uid", uob["objectId"]);
               person.save(null, {});
             },30000);

           });
```

The above code checks any changes in the location and adds the geopoint along with the objectid to parse core. But this happens whenever there is a change. I need to record the change only every 1 second. The above code records every time the gps cordinates changes. So sometimes it records 30-40 changes per minute.. i need only a single entry per minute..
How can i do this??

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getCurrentPosition()` to fetch a single position and then call it on a fixed interval. Something like this:

```
var opts = {
    enableHighAccuracy: true,
    timeout: 8000,
    maximumAge: 5000
};
var timer = setInterval(function(){
    $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(opts).then(function () { /* Not  used */
   },
   function (err) {

   }, function (position) {
     var lat  = position.coords.latitude;
     var long = position.coords.longitude;
     $scope.slat=lat;
     $scope.slong=long;
     var uob=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('meemp'));
     console.log(uob);
     var point = new Parse.GeoPoint({latitude: lat, longitude: long});
     console.log(point);
     console.log(uob["objectId"]);
     $timeout(function() {
       var PeopleObject = Parse.Object.extend("PeopleObject");
       var person = new PeopleObject();
       person.set("lat", point);
       person.set("uid", uob["objectId"]);
       person.save(null, {});
     },30000);

   });
}, 1000);
```

Comment: It will work so long as your app is in the foreground. if you need to record location while app is in the background, you'll need to use a different approach such as [cordova-background-geolocation](https://github.com/transistorsoft/cordova-background-geolocation-lt).